# Linq queries in Entity Framework 4. Horrible performance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, performance

In my project I'm using EntityFramework 4 for working with data. I found horrible performance problems with a simple query. When I looked at the profiler on a sql query, generated by EF4, I was shocked.

I have some tables in my entity data model:

[image: Data Model]

It looks pretty simple. I'm trying to select all product items from specified category with all related navigation properties.

I wrote this LINQ query:

```
ObjectSet<ProductItem> objectSet = ...; 
int categoryId = ...; 

var res = from pi in objectSet.Include("Product").Include("Inventory").Include("Inventory.Storage") 
where pi.Product.CategoryId == categoryId 
select pi;
```

EF generated this sql query:

```
SELECT   [Project1].[pintId1]          AS [pintId], 
[Project1].[pintId]           AS [pintId1], 
[Project1].[intProductId]     AS [intProductId], 
[Project1].[nvcSupplier]      AS [nvcSupplier], 
[Project1].[ nvcArticle]      AS [ nvcArticle], 
[Project1].[nvcBarcode]       AS [nvcBarcode], 
[Project1].[bIsActive]        AS [bIsActive], 
[Project1].[dtDeleted]        AS [dtDeleted], 
[Project1].[pintId2]          AS [pintId2], 
[Project1].[nvcName]          AS [nvcName], 
[Project1].[intCategoryId]    AS [intCategoryId], 
[Project1].[ncProductType]    AS [ncProductType], 
[Project1].[C1]               AS [C1], 
[Project1].[pintId3]          AS [pintId3], 
[Project1].[intProductItemId] AS [intProductItemId], 
[Project1].[intStorageId]     AS [intStorageId], 
[Project1].[dAmount]          AS [dAmount], 
[Project1].[mPrice]           AS [mPrice], 
[Project1].[dtModified]       AS [dtModified], 
[Project1].[pintId4]          AS [pintId4], 
[Project1].[nvcName1]         AS [nvcName1], 
[Project1].[bIsDefault]       AS [bIsDefault] 
FROM     (SELECT [Extent1].[pintId]         AS [pintId], 
[Extent1].[intProductId]   AS [intProductId], 
[Extent1].[nvcSupplier]    AS [nvcSupplier], 
[Extent1].[ nvcArticle]    AS [ nvcArticle], 
[Extent1].[nvcBarcode]     AS [nvcBarcode], 
[Extent1].[bIsActive]      AS [bIsActive], 
[Extent1].[dtDeleted]      AS [dtDeleted], 
[Extent2].[pintId]         AS [pintId1], 
[Extent3].[pintId]         AS [pintId2], 
[Extent3].[nvcName]        AS [nvcName], 
[Extent3].[intCategoryId]  AS [intCategoryId], 
[Extent3].[ncProductType]  AS [ncProductType], 
[Join3].[pintId1]          AS [pintId3], 
[Join3].[intProductItemId] AS [intProductItemId], 
[Join3].[intStorageId]     AS [intStorageId], 
[Join3].[dAmount]          AS [dAmount], 
[Join3].[mPrice]           AS [mPrice], 
[Join3].[dtModified]       AS [dtModified], 
[Join3].[pintId2]          AS [pintId4], 
[Join3].[nvcName]          AS [nvcName1], 
[Join3].[bIsDefault]       AS [bIsDefault], 
CASE 
WHEN ([Join3].[pintId1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) 
ELSE 1 
END AS [C1] 
FROM   [ProductItem] AS [Extent1] 
INNER JOIN [Product] AS [Extent2] 
ON [Extent1].[intProductId] = [Extent2].[pintId] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Product] AS [Extent3] 
ON [Extent1].[intProductId] = [Extent3].[pintId] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [Extent4].[pintId]           AS [pintId1], 
[Extent4].[intProductItemId] AS [intProductItemId], 
[Extent4].[intStorageId]     AS [intStorageId], 
[Extent4].[dAmount]          AS [dAmount], 
[Extent4].[mPrice]           AS [mPrice], 
[Extent4].[dtModified]       AS [dtModified], 
[Extent5].[pintId]           AS [pintId2], 
[Extent5].[nvcName]          AS [nvcName], 
[Extent5].[bIsDefault]       AS [bIsDefault] 
FROM   [Inventory] AS [Extent4] 
INNER JOIN [Storage] AS [Extent5] 
ON [Extent4].[intStorageId] = [Extent5].[pintId]) AS [Join3] 
ON [Extent1].[pintId] = [Join3].[intProductItemId] 
WHERE  [Extent2].[intCategoryId] = 8 /* @p__linq__0 */) AS [Project1] 
ORDER BY [Project1].[pintId1] ASC, 
[Project1].[pintId] ASC, 
[Project1].[pintId2] ASC, 
[Project1].[C1] ASC
```

For 7000 records in database and ~1000 record in specified category this query's execution time id around 10 seconds. It is not surprising if look at this:

```
FROM [ProductItem] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [Product] AS [Extent2]
ON [Extent1].[intProductId] = [Extent2].[pintId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Product] AS [Extent3]
ON [Extent1].[intProductId] = [Extent3].[pintId]
***LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ....***
```

Nested select in join... Horrible... I tried to change LINQ query, but I get same SQL query outputted.

A solution using stored procedures is not acceptable for me, because I'm using SQL Compact database.

Comment: Your english isn't that bad :) Well-formed question too. +1

Comment: You can use http://imgur.com/ to share images.

Comment: What's with the Includes? Why not just _from pi in objectSet where pi.Product.CategoryId == categoryId select pi_?

Comment: If you use hand-written SQL query, is the performance better?

Comment: +1 for comparison with hand-written SQL.  It's difficult to know how SQL Compact generally performs (well I sure as hell don't know)

Answer (score 7):

You are doing `Include("Product").Include("Inventory").Include("Inventory.Storage")` and you are wondering why so many records are fetched and why so see such a big SQL query? Please make sure you understand what the `Include` method is about. If you want a simpler query, please use the following:

```
var res =
    from pi in objectSet
    where pi.Product.CategoryId == categoryId 
    select pi;
```

Please note however that this will possible load `Products`, `Inventories` and `Storages` lazily, which could cause many more queries to be sent when you iterate over those sub collections.

Comment: +1 good point - with the Product:ProductItem (1:*) and ProductItem:Inventory (1:*), a single Product will load a whole lots of extra (possibly unneeded) data.... no wonder it's slow....

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the problem is with the Inventory collection in the Storage element. Your query will limit Product, ProductItem and Inventory items selected to those for the CategoryId specified.  However, in order to fill the Inventory collection of the Storage element, the query also has to return all Inventory rows that use the same StorageId's (and then all of the corresponding ProductItem and Product rows for those additional Inventory records.

I'd start by removing the Inventory collection from the Storage element or remove the corresponding include.